# How to read wWWHomePage from Azure Ad

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to read the `wWWHomePage` (a default Active Directory property) property of Users. The users are saved in Azure AD.

I tried to achieve my goal with the Microsoft Graph API, as implemented by the Microsoft.Graph NuGet package. However, Microsoft Graph does not implement the `wWWHomePage` property yet.

How can I read the `wWWHomePage` value?

Further information: It's an ASP.NET Core Web API project, running in Azure.

Comment: Have you looked through any of these questions?
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wWWHomePage

Comment: @Napoli yes I did. Can only find answers for Powershell or on prem AD.

Answer (score 0):

The `WWW-Home-Page` (or `wWWHomePage` in LDAP) isn't returned by Microsoft Graph. I would recommend adding this suggestion to [Microsoft Graph's UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: What would be the next best alternative that can return wWWHomePage?  Other O365 APIs are on the brink of obsoletion with Graph replacing all these specific APIs.

Comment: I added a UserVoice suggestion for my case. (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34177135-add-support-for-wwwhomepage) 

I still need a solution for the problem at hand, though.

Comment: There is no method for obtaining this from Microsoft Graph.

Comment: I understood that and thats why I asked for alternatives to Microsoft Graph. I did not say that I have to use Microsoft Graph. I only need a feasible way to get access to the content of the mentioned property.